# Many Error during updating angular 9 to 11

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I starting an Angular update on last Thursday and unfortunately, I'm working on it since then with a lot of errors.
The latest error while running ng serve -o is:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\dev\code\UI\trunk\MindoLifeDashboard\node_modules\angular-archwizard\archwizard.css'
See "C:\Users\Rami\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-cPGeAU\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

installed versions:

```
ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.2.5
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.5
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.5
@angular/cdk                    11.2.5
@angular/cli                    11.2.5
@angular/material               11.2.5
@schematics/angular             11.2.5
rxjs                            6.6.6
typescript                      4.2.3
```

When I install packages, I keep getting the following WARNS:

```
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.6 requires a peer of typescript@>=4.0 <4.2 but none is installed. 
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
 You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-morris-js@2.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@~11.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-morris-js@2.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@~11.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-packagr@11.2.4 requires a peer of typescript@>=4.0 <4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-echarts@6.0.1 requires a peer of resize-observer-polyfill@>=1.5.1 but none is installed. 
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@10.1.1 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tailwindcss@2.0.4 requires a peer of autoprefixer@^10.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-subresource-integrity@1.5.2 requires a peer of html-webpack-plugin@>= 2.21.0 < 5 but 
none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ node-sass@5.0.0
added 22 packages from 7 contributors, updated 6 packages, and audited 3139 packages in 52.431s        
found 12 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 moderate, 4 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I try to install the missing packages but it doesn't disappear from the warnings.

Any tips ???

Answer (score 1):

The warnings are due to the fact that some of your direct dependencies require specific versions of peer libraries, and that the versions of those libraries that you have installed are newer than the required ones.

For instance, you get the warning

```
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.6 requires a peer of typescript@>=4.0 <4.2 but none is installed.
```

because you have typescript 4.2.3 installed. You can either explicitly install an acceptable version with, e.g. `npm install typescript@4.1` or probably just ignore the warning, as long as a newer-than-required version is installed for each of the dependencies that generates a warning.

The bigger issue is the error. I'm guessing that you need to install the angular-archwizard library if you don't already have it installed, or maybe install a newer version?

Comment: I already installed the angular-archwizard, but this didn't help

Comment: Could be a version problem - maybe make sure that you have installed the same version that you had before the Angular upgrade?